# Insert dynamic PHP in Dojo declarative way

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it possible to insert dynamic declarative code into eg. a `borderContainer`? I've got a `borderContainer` and want to replace the 'center' content with the content of a file like `'/modules/example/example.php'`: (I've printed the output to my console)

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" id="centerPanel">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="lala"> yeahh </div>
</div>
```

When I call a function to remove the content it gives no errors. But when I want to add the dynamic content I get the following error: `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`. I guess this is because I haven't really defined the elements(and the Dojo parser has to parse the code).

Code of the '*add-declarative-dojo*'-function:

```
require(["dojo/text!../modules/" + file], function(file){
    console.log(file);
    registry.byId(mainLayout).addChild(file);
});
```

Is it possible to make this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually way easier than you're trying to do. The `dijit/layout/ContentPane` widget, which is the component you use inside any container (`dijit/layout/TabContainer` or `dijit/layout/BorderContainer`) actually has a property called `href` which you can use. For example:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" id="centerPanel">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="lala" data-dojo-props="href: 'myPage.php'"> yeahh </div>
</div>
```

And the reason why your code is not working is probably because you're passing a HTML page to the `addChild()`  function which only accepts widgets as you can read in the [API docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/layout/BorderContainer#1_9dijit_layout_LayoutContainer_addChild).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's solved, but the next problem(very cohesive) is that the `href` doesn't see my include files(like my language files). Is the only solution to include all necessary files? This doesn't sound like a good solution to me..

Comment: What do you mean by language files and how are they being included?

Comment: I've got an `index.php` where I include my language files(files, PHP,  with constants in it). After this I initialize my default startup screen(`BorderContainer`). I include files in Dojo with the suggested `href`, but after the inclusion my constants(included in the index) aren't working anymore(it is an 'one-page-app'). Also my `.on(clickevents)` aren't working in the `href` file. So, am I doing something terribly wrong or is the way I want to implement Dojo not like it should?

Comment: So these files are JavaScript files? Try looking at the `dojox/layout/ContentPane`, it has a property called `executeScripts` that evaluates content

Comment: All the files are in PHP. When I use the `href` property, the PHP is parsed like expected, but the includes are gone. I think this is because it is a XHR request. The only workaround I could think of is to create a separate inclusion file(PHP file where I include all my stuff).

Comment: If the includes are in PHP themself, then it should work fine (even when being an AJAX request).

Comment: I've mentioned it in a strange way. The language files were included in the index, not in the 'href-files'. I'm affraid I have to include the files in every requested file ;) Thanks for your help anyway!